# Adding a Secure Matser page in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

Good Day

How do you add a secure master page into the secure folder in Visual Studio? Is it a normal master page? How does it differ from the normal masterpage?

I have tried the following: Added a folder in my main root as: Secure. Inside that folder I have added a new master page and I named it Secure.Master. Now this will be the master page for any user that is logged...

It that all there is to it? Is a secure master page(logged in users) any different in Code Behind or anything than normal master pages for public users?

Thank you

Comment: I have tried the following: Added a folder in my main root as: Secure. Inside that folder I have added a new master page and I named it Secure.Master. Now this will be the master page for any user that is logged...

Comment: .NET Membership would appear to be the logical choice. Please see my answer for references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.net Membership  seems like a place for you to start reading about. It will allow you to secure sections of your site: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

You may also want to look at: http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages/ for a more simplified implementation i.e. `SimpleMemberhsip`

Comment: No problem David. I think someone may have down voted you as your original post showed no code/research for the question. StackOverflow can be a funny place at times :)